# Css for child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have few pages that have different structure inside the parent div

```
<div class="post-formatting">
     <p>some text
           <em>
                <a href="http://example.com">Click here</a>
           </em>
     </p>
 </div>
```

```html
<div class="post-formatting">
     <p>some text
           <a href="http://example-2.com">Click here</a>
     </p>
     <div>
           <a href="http://example-3.com">Click here</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

```html
<div class="post-formatting">
      <a href="http://example-4.com">Click here</a>
</div>
```

I need to set up a common CSS rule for all `<a>` tags within the `<div class="post-formatting">`, dependless whether it's a first child or not. 
Is there a way to do that? Thnx

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is very basic CSS. You can achieve this quite simply with:

```css
.post-formatting a {
    /* Your style declarations here. */
}
```

---

```css
.post-formatting a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-formatting">
  <p>
    some text
    <em>
      <a href="http://example.com">Click here</a>
    </em>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="post-formatting">
  <p>some text
    <a href="http://example-2.com">Click here</a>
  </p>
  <div>
    <a href="http://example-3.com">Click here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-formatting">
  <a href="http://example-4.com">Click here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't that only in sass/less?

Comment: @maex oops! It's been a long day! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* all a tags within .post-formatting */
.post-formatting a {
   /* css rules */
}

/* only the first a tag within .post-formatting */
.post-formatting a:first-child {
   /* css rules */
}

/* all but the first a tags in .post-formatting */
.post-formatting a:not(:first-child){
   /* css rules */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.post-formatting a {
/* your css */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-formatting > *:first-child a, .post-formatting > a:first-child {  }
```